# Install/Upgrade Python3.7 inside a Virtual Environment of Python 3.5

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am using a Python 3.5 virtual environment on a server having Python 2.7/3.5 without any admin(sudo) privileges. However, a specific task requires Python 3.7. I am looking for a way to upgrade/install this (or upgrade the virtual environment if possible) without affecting the whole machine.

Comment: You should check out `pyenv` (https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). It lets you install any/all python versions you want and allows them to be installed in your home directory (no root needed).

Comment: Thanks Mark. Your suggestion about pyenv was really handy. Though I opted for miniconda since it also uses the local home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Python virtual environments are very closely coupled with Python versions for which they were created. Even updating venv to a new bugfix release could be problematic. Upgrading to a new major release is impossible.

Create a different, new empty venv with Python 3.7. Activate it and install necessary packages.

Comment: The original intent of the question was whether I could do away with a new installation. But your statement and Mark's comment sorted that out.